# NextJS: Convert className function into styled components code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

so im watching a video tutorial and have code like this, but since im using styled-components im confuse about how to add `statusClass(0)` inside styled-components code

[image]

and this is my script:

- for styling like this

```js
const HasDone = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

const InProggress = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  animation: inProgress 1s ease infinite alternate;

  @keyframes inProgress {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
`;

const Undone = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.3;

`;
```

- call it here also make it function the same as a video

```
const Order = () => {
 const status = 0;

 const StatusClass = (index) => {
   if (index - status < 1) return HasDone;
   if (index - status === 1) return InProggress;
   if (index - status > 1) return Undone;
 };

 return (
   <Container>
     <Left>
       <Row>
         .....
       </Row>
       <Row>
         <StatusClass>
           <PaymentOutlined
             style={{ color: "black", width: "30", height: "30" }}
           />
           <span>Payment</span>
           <CheckedIcon>
             <CheckBoxOutlined
               style={{ color: "black", width: "30", height: "30" }}
             />
           </CheckedIcon>
         </StatusClass>
```

as you can see because I'm using styled-components changes the HTML element too.

if I try to change like this

`<StatusClass(0)>`

It gives me an error so how do I convert this to the styled component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are calling StatusClass right now will result in an object error, because React does not let objects be valid components. [This article](https://www.g2i.co/blog/understanding-the-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-error-in-react) can help understand that error better. However, to answer your question, you can just set a component equal to whichever index you want, and define that index via props (as i did in my example) or state. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vi1ik9?file=index.tsx) that might help.

Comment: okay thank you, but im using the next js tho, instead of passing to render that don't know where because using nextJS,
I want to pass it to the const can I do that so my code is like this

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sanne-2yirn1?file=/pages/test.jsx

Comment: don't mind me I typo there

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to ask with this comment. From the code snippet you gave, it looks like it would function fine, besides the missing component definitions